# Cannot handle null value exception on FindOne() C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, active-directory, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I am stuck on this line, **SearchResult searchResult=directorySearcher.FindOne()** it throws null value, I tried to handle it using various ways like if searchResult==null then this but apparently nothing is working.

how can I handle null values here? you help would be highly appreciated.

```
   try
  {
  DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry( activeDirectoryPath, userNameFull, password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
  DirectorySearcher directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry);


  SearchResult searchResult=directorySearcher.FindOne();

  foreach( string myKey in searchResult.Properties.PropertyNames )  
    {  
    string tab = "  ";  
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( myKey + " = " );  
    foreach( Object myCollection in searchResult.Properties[ myKey ] )  
      {
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( tab + myCollection );  
      }  
    }
  
  Result = true;
  return Result;  
  }
catch( Exception exception )
  {
  
  Log.LogError("IsNTPasswordValidDomain", "bool IsNTPasswordValidDomain( string username, string password, string domain )", exception.ToString());
  Result = false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If more than one entry is found during the search, only the first entry is returned. If no entries are found to match the search criteria, a null reference is returned. So first use `FindAll` then use `FirstOrDefault`.

```
var searchResults = directorySearcher.FindAll();
var searchResult = searchResults.FirstOrDefault();
if(searchResult != null)
{
   ....
}
```